# Django: Query multiple models based on parent model

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a blog in Django where I have a base model `PostType` which I then extend in to several subclasses for different types of content on the website. For example `CodeSnippet` and `BlogPost`.

The idea is that these content types are mostly the same, they all have an author, a title, a slug, etc, but they also have a few unique fields. For example a blog post has a field for the text content, while a code snippet has a related field for programming language.

Something like this:

```py
class PostType(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BlogPost(PostType):
    content = models.TextField(
        default='',
    )


class GitHubRepo(PostType):
    url = models.URLField(
        unique=True
    )


class CodeSnippet(PostType):
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Language,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Now what I want to know is if there's any good/prefered way to query all objects in the database that are based on the parent class `PostType`?

For the site's search I am currently querying each of the different content types, and then merging the result. This is the code for the search view:

```
class Search(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {}
        try:
            query = request.GET.get('s')
            blog_list = models.BlogPost.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
            projects_list = models.Project.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
            code_list = models.CodeSnippet.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
            from itertools import chain
            context['result_list'] = list(chain(blog_list, projects_list, code_list))

        except KeyError:
            query = ''

        context['title'] = 'Result for "{}"'.format(query)

        return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

This all works fine, but I would like to know if there's any way to query all children of `PostType` at the same time?

Is Django somehow aware of what child models exist? And can I use that somehow?

Like a `PostType.child_objects.get()` or something similar. 
Even a way to programmatically get all the children so that I could loop through them and get all the objects would be fine too.

For the time being I just have a few models, but the number of child models were to increase, it would be great if I could be assured that all the models would be included in the site search automatically based on their relationship to their parent model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PostType` is an abstract `Model` (So, it does not create physical table. It's just to use inheritance feature in Django). As far as i understand you want to generate `list` of `QuerySet`'s merge it in a single `list` and iterate over `list/QuerySet` later.

```
get_qs_list = [model.objects.filter(title__icontains=query) for model in PostType.__subclasses__()] # This contains QuerySet instances now.
for qs in get_qs_list:
    # qs iterator returns QuerySet instance
    for instance in qs:
        # instance iterator is single Model instance from QuerySet collection
        print(instance.title)
```

Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If `PostType` is not an abstract model then you should be able to query it directly to get all those subclass results

```
PostType.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
```

Otherwise, you cannot really do this with a single query.

> Even a way to programmatically get all the children so that I could
>   loop through them and get all the objects would be fine too.

This is possible --- to get the subclasses programmatically, you would do

```
PostType.__subclasses__()
```

Comment: Sorry, `PostType` is an abstract model. It seems I accidently cut that piece of the class out when I removed a bunch of methods unrelated to my question. Sorry about that! I will edit the question. I will try the `PostType.__subclasses__()` approach and see how it works.

Comment: @Jeffrey The `PostType.__subclasses__()` approach worked like a charm.